# Array Collection persistence on symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

i'm using a event listener on the submit of a form where, i need to catch a xml file, open it and extract his contents, put it on an entity and add that to a collection from other entity.

right now this is works:

```
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event){
        $entity = $event->getData();
        if($entity){
            $parent = $event->getForm()->getParent()->getData();
            $gpx = $entity['gpx'];
            if($gpx){
                $xmlGpx = simplexml_load_file($gpx);
                foreach ($xmlGpx->wpt as $pt) {
                    $point = new MonitoringPoint();
                    $point->setPoint(new \CrEOF\Spatial\PHP\Types\Geometry\Point((string) $pt['lat'], (string) $pt['lon']));
                    $point->setAltitude((float) $pt->ele);
                    $point->setDate(($pt->time->count() ? new \DateTime((string)$pt->time) : null ));
                    $point->setAccuracy((float) $pt->hdop);
                    $parent->addMonitoringPoint($point);
                }

                $fileName = $gpx->getClientOriginalName();
                $directory = __DIR__.'/../../../../web/uploads/';
                $date =  new \DateTime();

                $newFileName = md5($gpx->getClientOriginalName().$date->getTimestamp());
                $gpx->move($directory, $fileName);
                $fs = new Filesystem();
                $fs->rename($directory.$fileName, $directory.$newFileName.'.gpx');
                $parent->setGpx($newFileName.'.gpx');

            }
        }
    });
```

`$parent` is an instance of `Monitoring`, if i open `$parent` i will see that the `$point` vars has been added on the collection `monitoringPoints` of the variable, and the gpx too.

but then i go so see the entity right before been persisted, inside newAction

```
    $entity = new Monitoring($params);

    $form = $this->createForm(new MonitoringType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('my_route'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        dump($entity);die;
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

and the collection is empty! but the gpx attribute contains the right value.
does the collection gets reseted?

Comment: make sure to read and understand http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html - i am pretty sure this is your issue.

Answer (score 0):

i had to pass the points in to an array within the session, still think that was not the best option, but worked

```
$array = [];
foreach ($xmlGpx->wpt as $pt) {
    $point = new MonitoringPoint();
    $point->setPoint(new \CrEOF\Spatial\PHP\Types\Geometry\Point((string) $pt['lat'], (string) $pt['lon']));
    $point->setAltitude((float) $pt->ele);
    $point->setDate(($pt->time->count() ? new \DateTime((string)$pt->time) : null ));
    $point->setAccuracy((float) $pt->hdop);
    $point->setMonitoring($parent);
    array_push($array, $point);
}
$session = new Session();
$session->getFlashBag()->add('array', $array);
```

in the newAction:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$session = new Session();
$array = $session->getFlashBag()->get('array');
foreach($array[0] as $point) {
    $point->setMonitoring($entity);
    $entity->addMonitoringPoint($point);
}

$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

dont know why the array got reseted when it comes to the controller, cause i had setted the points in the entity during the submit